# Sort by price not working correctly in bookable products

Tags: woocommerce-bookings

It seems the sorting filter doesn’t work correctly with the bookable products, the conflict was with the booking plugin, I added simple products and tested the sorting it works.
Now, Can you help me to make it work correctly with the bookable products? or can you suggest another plugin for sorting work with bookable products.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please see this post to edit a question for the community to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Price/Cost calculation for bookable products is much more involved than other type of products, there could be hundreds/thousands of possibilities for a single Booking depending on how the product / booking is configured.